# Qt/KDE implementation of XDG Recent File Storage spec?

Tags: qt

Gtk has built in support for the [Freedesktop Recent Files spec](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/recent-file-spec/); is there a similar thing I can call from a Qt app?

Answer (score 0):

In KDE, [KRecentFilesAction](http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kconfigwidgets/html/classKRecentFilesAction.html) implements the recent files feature. However, it doesn't seem to use the Freedesktop Recent Files spec. Qt doesn't ship one. You may be interested in this [Qt demo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-recentfiles-mainwindow-cpp.html), but strictly speaking this is also not what you want. Also, it seems the there is another [XDG spec](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-bookmark-spec/) that is supposed to replace the recent files spec. So a different/custom implementation might not be that wrong after all :)